# how do I add a comment when hovering over a form button?

Tags: ms-access, button, command

I'm trying to add a comment that appears when the mouse hovers over a form button, but disappears once you stop pointing to the button. How do I accomplish this?

I tried adding the comment in the **other** tab in the **property sheet** menu, but it does not accomplish what I wish to do. Any DETAILED instructions explaining how to do this would be great.

Comment: Please provide more details, for example, what software you are using, how exactly are you trying to achieve this, how is it related to programming, post your code examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the `MouseMove` Events for your button and the surrounding form section (which is likely to be Form Detail).

In the below example, the visibility of the label is toggled when the mouse is moved between the button and form detail section:

[image]

The above is driven by the following two event handlers:

```vb
Private Sub Detail_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If MyComment.Visible Then MyComment.Visible = False
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub MyButton_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Not MyComment.Visible Then MyComment.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Here, the button is named `MyButton` and the label containing the comment is named `MyComment`.